# Docker - How can i find running container?

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a container linked with another:

`docker run -d -P --name XXX --link rds:rds ZZZ/KK`K

Error response from daemon:

> Conflict. The name "XXX" is already in use by container b73b7f91fccf. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

When I run `docker ps`, I am unable to see the container b73b7f91fccf.

Why can't I see the b73b7f91fccf container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker ps` (with no options) only shows running containers.  To list *all* extant containers, run `docker ps -a`.